# How to diplay subscripts and array elements simultaneously on r plot

Tags: r, plot, escaping

I have a coefficient array `bees` created in the following way:

`gfit = lm(y_data,x_data);`

`bees = coef(gfit);`, where `bees[1]=0.123`, `bees[2]=4.56`

A plot `plot(x_data,y_data)` is created. I'd liket to add some text on this plot. The text should look like $b_0=0.123, b_1=4.55$ (how to add Latex symbols on StackOverflow?).

I tried the following command: `text(3,15,expression(paste("b"[0],"="bees[1])));`, which turns out to be $b_0=bees_1$, i.e. the variable bees[1] is not interpreted properly.

How can I display the value of a variable by typing its name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R doesn't have a LaTeX interpreter. You need to use `?plotmath`. Try using `bquote` to allow getting values of R-objects , and here assuming that (1,1) is in the range of your (undescribed) data. The `.()`-function will put values pulled from the working environment into expressions:

```
 text(1,1, bquote( list( b[0] == .(bees[1]) , b[1] == .(bees[2]) ) ) )
```

See the examples in `?bquote`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing formulas is a horrible mess in R. Only regexp is more write-only.

```
bees=c(0.12, 4.56)
plot(rnorm(100))
text(30,0,bquote(bees[1]== .(bees[1])))
```